# I want to make a button that open browser and then redirect to phone dialer

Tags: android, html, ios, redirect, browser

I want to make a button that opens a browser and then redirects you to the phone dialer. I can only use links for the buttons. Its not working with  function. The button property only supports "http://" requests. Its not possible without http:. I dont have an option to add a script.  Can somebody help me?

Comment: Are you done any programming then please post that so we are able to understand and suggest changes.

Comment: Are you aware of the `tel:` URI scheme? Doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: Yes i tried with tel:. But the problem is its from an app. For button it support only http link. So i want to add http link which can redirect to phone dialer app

Comment: Y u need to open the browser? U can directly open the dialer on clicking the button

Comment: @Navaneethan i cant use <a href:"tel:2132245464564"> for button. My app doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0):

In Button OnClick Listener just call the below

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The button property only support "http://" request. Not possible with out http:. And dont have option to add script

Comment: In .java file u want to write this code. U need to set "setOnClickListener" for the button.